# Seeking to optimize use of parentNode and nextElementSibling

Tags: javascript, dom, onclick, event-handling

On this coding exercise, tt took me a while to figure out how to reference the class that gets hidden here, and now that it's working, it would be a shame to break it, however, it was my hope to refactor this thing so the reference to the class that needs to be hidden is cleaner.

As you can see, doubling up on nextElementSibling to traverse the tree costs in hard coding the solution for each adaptive reuse. My hope was to simply change the classes queried. To do this, at first, it looked like using this.querySelector('* +') might be the answer, but after many attempts (maybe not the right ones b/c it still might work unless you tell me otherwise) it failed.

The following does work:

```
        let el = this.parentNode.firstChild
        el = el.nextElementSibling
        el = el.nextElementSibling
```

So, how can the class .acc-body be referenced in a simpler way given the HTML outline it acts on?

And, since the approach to event handing put into force here is decidedly non-standard, and probably not recommended, is that reason enough to avoid using this in production?

```html
<div class="acc">
        <div class="acc-item">
            <!-- <div class="acc-title"> -->
            <h1 class="acc-title" id="btn_hide">Click to hide the Body</h1>

            <!-- </div> -->
            <div class="acc-body hideable">
                <p id="head1">Why innerHTML is so great...</p>
            </div>   
        </div> 
        <div class="acc-item"> 
            <h1 class="acc-title" id="other_btn_hide_xxxx">Click to hide the Body</h1>

            <div class="acc-body hideable">
                <p id="head2">Why innerHTML is so great...</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Implemented as an IIFE; recommend it be placed in its own .js file and referenced from a script tag in the HTML document.

```js
        (function() {
        console.log('ready to assign event handler to chosen nodelist of elements')
        // returned as a nodelist
        all = document.querySelectorAll(".acc-item .acc-title")
        console.log(all);

        // document[selectionMethod(element)]
        // element.selectionMethod.classList
        console.log('setAttribute \'clickable\' received on: -----------');
        all.forEach ( (j) => {
            console.log(j);
            // j.setAttribute('onclick', 'showhide(this)')
            j.setAttribute('clickable', 'true')
            j.classList.add("clickable")
        })

        console.log('listen for onclick on: ----------');
        all.forEach( (j) => {
            console.log(j);
            j.onclick = function () {
            // alert(this);
            // let el = this.querySelector('* +')
            let el = this.parentNode.firstChild
            el = el.nextElementSibling
            el = el.nextElementSibling
            console.log(el);
            if (el.hidden){
                el.hidden = false
            } else {
                el.hidden = true
            }
            }
        })
    })()
```

Comment: What about `:nth-child(2)` ?

Comment: Your code is illogical. `document.querySelectorAll('.acc-body')`, can get that Array Like Object... but, what are you really trying to achieve? By the way that poorly and incorrectly written self executing function wrapper is not `addEventListener('load', function(){ /* your code here */ });`

Comment: @SlackSlave I'm not sure what you mean. Since it works, I wonder what it might do that specifically makes it bad? It was written purposely to avoid addEventListener, applying a click event to classes contained in a specific way. If you know how it violates good practice, by causing a buffer overrun, or something, please specify the nature of its bad if you know it..